# React REST request to Java backend failing

Tags: java, reactjs, fetch

I have a simple React form. I am trying to send the data from this form using Fetch API to my Java backend. Here is my React Form file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={value:""};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({value:event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/add/person', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Name: 
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    );  
    }
}
```

For some reason, the data variable always has an empty JSON when I am in debug mode. In my Java backend, when I receive the request, I am seeing blank form data.

Any ideas as to why I am not able to send data across to my Java backend?

EDIT: I would also like to point out that my frontend is hosted on localhost:3000, while my Java backend server is on localhost:8080

Comment: when you open your console are you getting a CORS issue due to different host?

Comment: YES!!! I get the following error in the console:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Comment: is this app created using `Create React App`?

Comment: Yes it is. Is that causing this issue?

Comment: updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

why not just submit your data using the value stored in state?

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = this.state.value; //change here

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/add/person', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
}
```

UPDATE: in your package.json add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` if that doesn't work you will have to open it up using something like this but for what ever framework you're using on your backend.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

as @Tadas Antanavicius said your input is also missing a name value. here is a nice and short medium article on the react portion of what you are trying to do with your code. you can even remove your onChange from your input field.
https://medium.com/@everdimension/how-to-handle-forms-with-just-react-ac066c48bd4f

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joshua! I want to submit the form data alone, which is why I am trying to convert the form data to a FormData() object and then send that across

Comment: Setting the proxy worked. Now I am not getting any CORS related errors. However, my backend is still unable to get any data from the frontend

Comment: Did you add a name to your input?

Comment: Yes I did. The way it worked for me was that I had to collect the key-value pairs from the FormData() object and make a new JSON object that ended up being the request payload

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is unrelated to your backend - the `fetch` code looks correct.

`FormData` is not being constructed as you would expect. You can try this out by opening Chrome Devtools' Network tab and watch the request as it goes by: empty request payload.

The problem is that the `FormData` constructor's argument relies on each `input` in the form having a `name` attribute, which you're missing. If you add it, (`name="name"`) your front end should behave as expected:

```js
<input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

EDIT: As per your above conversation, seems like you also have a server side CORS issue. My answer fixes your original question, but yes you'll need to resolve the CORS one as well, the easiest way probably being to refer to the docs of whatever Java framework you're using. It's a very common problem and should be in FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am seeing the data. Thanks so much!